# How to avoid creating of new floatBuffer every time when I change color or coordinates in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I have very simple vertex shader like:

```
uniform mat4 u_Matrix;
uniform float u_PointSize;

attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec4 a_Color;

varying vec4 v_Color;

void main() {
   v_Color = a_Color;
   gl_PointSize = u_PointSize;
   gl_Position = u_Matrix * a_Position;
}
```

and I initialize float buffer like:

```
floatBuffer = ByteBuffer
.allocateDirect(vertexData.length * Constants.BYTES_PER_FLOAT)
.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
.asFloatBuffer()
.put(vertexData);
```

Where vertexData contains for example values like (X, Y, R, G, B):

```
float[] vertexData = new float[] {100, 100, 1f, 0f, 0f}
```

When I want to change coordinates (there are some cases when I really need it and working with transformation matrices isn't the solution) or color I need to:

- Change necessary values in vertexData array
- Create new ByteBuffer

It looks like bad solution since it creates new byte buffer by calling ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(..) every time I want to change color/coordinates.

Could you clarify which way might be better?

I thought about using uniforms for color and use glUniformMatrix4fv(..) every time I need to change/restore color but I'm not sure it's good way too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code can avoid to call allocate every time you update vertex data. I never tried to use allocateDirect with this code, but it might work.

```
// allocate
FloatBuffer mVertexData = FloatBuffer.allocate(size);

// update
for (int i = 0; i < vertexNum; ++i) {
    mVertexData.put( vertexData );
}
mVertexData.rewind();

// draw    
gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, mVertexData, gl.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```